# Luv says "Sorry about that" -- what is she referring to?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

When K first meets her in the data repository, when she opens a door, she says, "Sorry about that." No idea why she says that.

Answer (score 3):

**Because the *door jams* half-open delaying their entry into that section of the archive:**

> No-one's been down here in ages.

She manually forces the door to fully open allowing them passage:

[image: Her manhandling the door.]

> Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The [original script](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf) doesn't have her apologising, but it does explain what the door jamming scene is supposed to convey; that this is an archive of ancient information that nobody accesses, and also to show that Luv is a new model Replicant (and possibly one that's even more advanced than Officer K).

> **LUV:** *Here -- all the junk is in here. Lucky for you Mr. Wallace is a data hoarder. A shard in the right shape can be a gem.*
>
> She leans into a FACIAL RECOGNITION SCAN. It unlatches -- but stops
> before opening. STUCK. A nuisance.
>
> **LUV:** *No one’s been down here in ages.*
>
> Without a break in stride she PRIES into the door seam with her
> FINGERS to OPEN it. A show of tremendous force. Perhaps deliberate.
> After you...